# How can I reuse a function to order different attributes of an object

Tags: python, list, oop

I have a class. We'll say the class has the following attributes: age, height, weight, IQ.

I want to print the top 5 instances of this object in all categories. For example, 5 oldest, 5 smartest, 5 tallest.

I would like to use 1 function that I could call in 4 different ways to get this done.

For example:

```
def topNOfAttribute(people,attr,num=5):
    people.sort(key=lambda x:x.attr,reverse=True)
    toDisplay=[x for x in people if x.attr>=people[num-1].attr]
    print toDisplay
```

In theory, I'd be able to call it like so
topNOfAttribute(people,'age')
topNOfAttribute(people,'height')

Rather than creating 4 functions, 1 for age, 1 for height, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr`

```
def topNOfAttribute(people, attr_name, num=5):
    sorted_people = sorted(people, key=lambda x: getattr(x, attr_name), reverse=True)
    toDisplay = sorted_people[:num]
    print toDisplay
```

Usage:

```
topNOfAttribute(people, 'age')
```

I also simplified how you were getting the top-n using slicing. It's generally not good to mutate your arguments in a function. So create a copy of the list inside with `sorted`

Answer (score 0):

Using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), this can easily be turned into a one-liner.

## Code (Python 3.5)

```
from pprint import pprint

class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, age, height, weight, iq):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.iq = iq

    def __repr__(self):
        return str({'age': self.age, 'height': self.height, 'weight': self.weight, 'iq': self.iq})

def top(objects, attr, num=5):
    return sorted(objects, key=lambda x: getattr(x, attr), reverse=True)[:num]

students = [
    Student(age=21, height=127, weight=168, iq=120),
    Student(age=24, height=120, weight=120, iq=50),
    Student(age=19, height=110, weight=400, iq=90),
    Student(age=30, height=190, weight=30, iq=92),
    Student(age=31, height=180, weight=168, iq=77),
    Student(age=42, height=169, weight=168, iq=98)
]

pprint(top(students, 'iq'))
```

## Results

```
[{'age': 21, 'iq': 120, 'weight': 168, 'height': 127},
 {'age': 42, 'iq': 98, 'weight': 168, 'height': 169},
 {'age': 30, 'iq': 92, 'weight': 30, 'height': 190},
 {'age': 19, 'iq': 90, 'weight': 400, 'height': 110},
 {'age': 31, 'iq': 77, 'weight': 168, 'height': 180}]
```